# Prevent apt-get from using a specific mirror

Tags: apt, repository

I am using [Cubian X1](https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/), a customized Debian wheezy distro, on my Cubietruck ARM board.

Running **apt-get update** fails, as it tries to connect to `mirror.isoc.org.il` mirror which is filtered inside Iran, along with other domain/IPs hosted in Israel.

Here is the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.cubian.org/ wheezy main non-free
deb http://repo.ajenti.org/debian main main debian
```

I've commented out the **isoc.org.il** references inside these two files too:

- /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.mirrors
- /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Debian.mirrors

But **apt-get update** still fails with the following messages:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:80 (192.115.211.70). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:
```

I am not sure why apt-get still tries to a mirror like mirror.isoc.org.il. Maybe it is recognized as the closest mirror. Is there any way to guide apt-get to connect to another mirror?

The folllowing is the full **apt-get update** output:

```
cubie@Cubian:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://repo.ajenti.org main Release.gpg [490 B]
Get:2 http://packages.cubian.org wheezy Release.gpg [316 B]
Hit http://repo.ajenti.org main Release
Get:3 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg [836 B]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://repo.ajenti.org main/main armhf Packages
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main armhf Packages
Get:4 http://http.debian.net wheezy Release.gpg [1,655 B]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Get:5 http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release.gpg [836 B]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free armhf Packages
Get:6 http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg [836 B]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian Translation-en_US
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian Translation-en
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Fetched 4,969 B in 18s (268 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
cubie@Cubian:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://repo.ajenti.org main Release.gpg [490 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Get:2 http://repo.ajenti.org main Release [11.1 kB]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://repo.ajenti.org main/main armhf Packages
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian armhf Packages [1,468 B]
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://packages.cubian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/debian Translation-en
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.ajenti.org main/main Translation-en
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy Release.gpg
  Could not connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:80 (192.115.211.70). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy Release
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports Release
Ign http://http.debian.net wheezy/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net wheezy/contrib armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net wheezy/non-free armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/contrib armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/non-free armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/non-free armhf Packages
Fetched 13.1 kB in 2min 9s (101 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:80 (192.115.211.70). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to mirror.isoc.org.il:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the way to remove Replese.gpg as [mark said](https://askubuntu.com/a/604094/25983).

Nevertheless, I also get similar errors during `apt-get install` as apt-get still tried to connect to `isoc.org.il`.

To reslove the issue, I generated the first 4 lines with a fixed mirror (US mirror) using [debgen.simplylinux.ch](http://debgen.simplylinux.ch). Here is the final working `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.cubian.org/ wheezy main non-free
deb http://repo.ajenti.org/debian main main debian
```

Answer (score -1):

Open "software and updates" from the dash.

Choose the "other software" tab.

Find these three lines and uncheck or delete them.

```
http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg

http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-backports/Release.gpg

http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release.gpg
```

Now you can

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Should be fine.

EDIT: To remove repos via terminal please see [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) extensive answer

These repos must be removed as they no longer exist, when apt tries to update your packages it can't find these repos and reports the "Failed to fetch" error, in your specific case canonical must of remover these old repositories.

Comment: How could I do this via terminal? How you mind to explain why they are not necessary?